# Firemokey action select photo from gallery or make a picture

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I know it is possible with Android (see the post [Android let user pick/capture photo from gallery or camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143795/android-let-user-pick-capture-photo-from-gallery-or-camera)).

But is this also possible with FireMonkey?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Taking_and_Sharing_a_Picture,_and_Sharing_Text_(iOS_and_Android)

Comment: The 3 sample apps in the Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Snippets (as well as the two in the Samples\Object Pascal\Mobile Samples\Media) should get you started.

Comment: Demo: http://www.fmxexpress.com/instagram-filters-clone-source-code-for-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/

Comment: I meant one button and then the Android/IOS action to choose wether you can take a photo or choose one from the gallery.

Comment: You can make your own Modal for this if you want that